# INNER JOIN with more AND

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables.

```
table one: items
table two: items_options
```

now i need a search for 2 options_ids on table two

```
SELECT i.id FROM items as i
INNER JOIN items_options as io ON i.item_id = i.id 
WHERE io.option_id = 60143 AND io.option_id = 60142  
ORDER BY i.xy ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

How can i do it without group by/having?

Comment: `WHERE io.option_id = 60143 OR io.option_id = 60142`?

Comment: What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: i want all items which have the item option 60143 and the item option 60142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want `OR` or use an `IN` statement.

```
SELECT i.id 
    FROM items as i
INNER JOIN items_options as io
    ON i.item_id = i.id 
WHERE io.option_id IN (60143, 60142)
ORDER BY i.xy ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

OR

```
SELECT i.id 
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN items_options as io 
    ON i.item_id = i.id 
WHERE io.option_id = 60143 OR io.option_id = 60142  
ORDER BY i.xy ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

You cannot have an `option_id` that has both values.

EDIT: If you want both values you can use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
SELECT x.id
FROM
(
  SELECT i.id, i.xy
  FROM items as i
  INNER JOIN items_options as io 
    ON i.item_id = i.id 
  WHERE io.option_id = 60143 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.id, i.xy
  FROM items as i
  INNER JOIN items_options as io 
    ON i.item_id = i.id 
  WHERE io.option_id = 60142  
) x
ORDER BY i.xy ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Or you could try joining on the `items_options` table twice:

```
SELECT i.id 
FROM items as i
INNER JOIN items_options as io1 
  ON i.item_id = io1.id 
INNER JOIN items_options as io2 
  ON i.item_id = io2.id 
WHERE io1.option_id = 60143 AND io2.option_id = 60142  
ORDER BY i.xy ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Comment: no i want all items which have the item option 60143 and the item option 60142

Comment: yes your last example seems good, but is it fast

if i search after 10 option ids i need 10 join? (half million rows..)

Comment: @user1576248 if you wanted to restrict them prior to the join, then you could make those subqueries and place the `limit` inside

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want an `OR` in place of `AND`.  There won't be any rows from items_options that satisfy both conditions.

```
WHERE io.option_id = 60143 OR io.option_id = 60142
                           ^^
```

Alternatively,

```
WHERE io.option_id IN (60143,60142)
```

---

You mention not wanting to use GROUP BY. It sounds as if you don't want to return duplicate items.id values. You could add a DISTINCT keyword before the SELECT list to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id FROM items as i
```

Answer (score 0):

It might work better to use an `OR` here rather than an `AND`. `AND` suggests that the two conditions can happen at the same time. Since you are looking for rows that have `option_id = 60143` and also rows that have `option_id = 60142`, using `OR` would get you rows that have either of them.

```
SELECT i.id FROM items as i
INNER JOIN items_options as io ON i.item_id = i.id 
WHERE io.option_id = 60143 OR io.option_id = 60142  
ORDER BY i.xy ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

Comment: no i want all items which have the item option 60143 and the item option 60142